# python3.6 install uwsgi error centos

Tags: python-3.x, centos, uwsgi

I successfully installed uwsgi on local.

But i installed on vps then it's error.

Currently I do not know how to fix it.

Error message:

*** uWSGI compiling embedded plugins ***
    [Gcc -pthread] plugins / python / pythonplugin.o
    In file included from plugins / python / pythonplugin.c: 1: 0:
    Plugins / python / uwsgipython.h: 2: 20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include 
                        ^
    Compilation terminated.

```
----------------------------------------
```

"/usr/bin/python2.7 -u -c" import setuptools, tokenize; _ file __ = '/ tmp / pip-build-oONRqq / superset / setup.py'; f = getattr (tokenize, 'open', open Exec (compile (code, file, 'exec')) "install - (__ file __); code = f.read () replace ('\ r \ n', '\ n' -record /tmp/pip-ktDXj1-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile "failed with error code 1 in / tmp / pip-build-oONRqq /
I look forward to your help.
Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. My quick solution is change python version down to 3.5+. It worked for me. What is the main problem I don't know.